# Rails + Passenger + Nginx error Request Origin (domainname.com) does not match Request Base_url (IP Address)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, request-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

Set up:
Rails 5.1.3, Dreamhost VPS with Passenger and Nginx.
As it is a VPS, I do not have root access to perform any function that would require root permissions.

Situation: Currently, I have redone a previous rails app with ActionCable functionality. Earlier configuration was with Apache instead of Nginx for the http server. Everything works fine except for websockets, and I read quite a few articles, all confirming action cables + apache will not work.

At which point, I switched to NginX. With NginX, my first observation was that the application constantly tries the 'get cable/' process and fails to upgrade to websocket. After reading through various discussions I managed to solve this with:

```
location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/cable;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

As I do not have root permission to access the usual dt/etc/nginx/.../***.conf file, with the dreamhost VPS package, I can add a file at /home/username/nginx/(appname.com)/(any-file-name.conf) and this would add on to the nginx "server block", as per dreamhost documentation.

^^So the above block of code alone in a file called "redis.conf" in that directory sorted the action cables issue. It successfully starts streaming on channels everything is fine.

The main issue, I later realize, is that I cannot perform any of the create, update, destroy actions - anything that needs POST or DELETE methods as it results in an authenticity token error, saying "The Request Origin (http ://siik.io - *this being the app & domain name*) did not match the request.base_url (http ://127.0.0.1).

Detail Error:

```
I, [2017-09-11T03:27:28.623080 #7273]  INFO -- : [50a21156-0333-413e-94b

8-07b791c209fc] Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 56.0ms | ActiveRecord: 16.6ms)
I, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.950732 #7273]  INFO -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] Started POST "/conversations/1/messages" for 106.208.156.243 at 2017-09-11 03:27:31 -0700
I, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.953339 #7273]  INFO -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
I, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.953511 #7273]  INFO -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "body"=>"sdfgh"}, "commit"=>"Send", "conversation_id"=>"1"}
W, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.954325 #7273]  WARN -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] HTTP Origin header (http://www.siik.io) didn't match request.base_url (http://127.0.0.1:8000)
I, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.954890 #7273]  INFO -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.956888 #7273] FATAL -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d]   
F, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.956969 #7273] FATAL -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
F, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.957017 #7273] FATAL -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d]   
F, [2017-09-11T03:27:31.957126 #7273] FATAL -- : [dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in `handle_unverified_request'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:227:in `handle_unverified_request'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:253:in `handle_unverified_request'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:222:in `verify_authenticity_token'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activerecord (5.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionview (5.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in serve'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] passenger (5.1.8) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] passenger (5.1.8) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:160:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] passenger (5.1.8) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] passenger (5.1.8) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[dd8e08f7-f28b-497b-9ae9-e57a6a45c35d] passenger (5.1.8) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

BUT, when I access the site through http ://siik.io:8000 EVERYTHING works perfectly, even the websockets bit without the need for redis.conf file.

I've gone through a week's worth of various fixes and documentations and have failed to find the solution for this. I think the basic requirement is to add more headers onto a location / {} block to add on to the nginx.conf file... (I've listed some examples I've tried below.)

```
listen 80;
listen *:80;
server_name siik.io www.siik.io http://siik.io;
location / {

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:8000;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr:8000;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

.. So I've basically being trying various combinations & permutations for the above values to see what works because clearly, I have no clue how this works - I have some conceptual knowledge on reverse proxying and http servers.

Yes, I know the request.origin == request.base_url thing is from the protect_from_forgery bit of rails, I don't feel switching it off is a solution, although, I did read somewhere that including the right headers will solve this issue. I've tried a few variations of this header sets and none worked, and am wondering if including the right headers should reach a point where the http origin header will change from domainname.io to an IP address or the request.base_url will change from the IP address to the domainname??

Oh yes, when I add the location / {} block in a new file proxy.conf next to redis.conf it completely breaks. The website via domainname.io refuses to connect, while domainname.io:8000 works perfectly. Even an empty block under location / breaks it - I was testing to see if any specific proxy_set commands were causing it to break - but no. Just the bits "location / {}" breaks it - maybe this is expected?

Why does this work perfectly when I access it via siik.io:8000, with the port number explicitly?

Any help is EXTREMELY appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to run your action cable server on another port, try following these instructions: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/

Copied here per THE RULES™:

## Running the Action Cable server on the same host and port, under a sub-URI

This is the default setup as recommended by Rails and is also the easiest. It works by mounting `ActionCable.server` to a certain path in your `config/routes.rb`. That way, your Action Cable server will be running on the same host and port as your application, but under a sub-URI.

For example, your `routes.rb` may contain:

```
# Serve websocket cable requests in-process
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

(Although the `routes.rb` comment says that mounting `ActionCable.server` is meant for serving it in-process, Passenger actually insists on running it as a separate process.)

To make this work in Passenger + Nginx, you need to add a snippet to your Nginx virtual host. Suppose that you already had a virtual host for your application, which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.foo.com;
    root /path-to-your-app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

You need to insert a location block which configures the Action Cable end point, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.foo.com;
    root /path-to-your-app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    ### INSERT THIS!!! ###
    location /cable {
        passenger_app_group_name YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE_action_cable;
        passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
    }
}
```

Replace `/cable` with the actual Action Cable path as is specified in your routes.rb.

Replace `YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE` with a unique identifier that doesn't appear anywhere else in the Nginx configuration file.

The `passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process` option tunes Passenger for optimal WebSocket performance.

Comment: thanks @camden, I'm going to try this out for the action cables bit, but (perhaps I misrepresented my current problem) - when I take the actioncables "location /cable" block out of the equation, the primary problem still remains: accessing my application via just the --domainname.io-- results in the error HTTP REQUEST ORIGIN (DOMAINNAME.IO) DOES NOT MATCH THE REQUEST.BASE_URL (THE IP ADDRESS), whenever I perform a login, logout, create, destroy - anything.

Comment: [i hit enter key prematurely sorry...] 
so the problem of that authenticity token part due to mismatch between http://www.siik.io and http://127.0.0.1:8000 still remains regardless what fix is added for the action cables. I think the action cables is an isolated problem, I mentioned that to explain why I switched from apache to nginx. If your suggestion was to run passenger in standalone + apache for running action cables, im keen to try it out. Only, nginx boasts a better handling or ram and processes. I would like to explore how I may fix just the nginx redirects first though.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED.

I'm not completely sure how this was resolved, I'm still trying to figure out why everything is working.
Basically, the issue seemed to be with the way in which the Passenger+Nginx configuration was maintained. - This is a dreamhost specific issue I believe.

My initial VPS configuration was done with Apache as the http server following a tutorial by Dave Jones on youtube. In the domain hosting section of the Dreamhost panel there's a checkbox to use Passenger with the ruby application which was left unchecked as per the original tutorial I was following.
Reading up on @Camden's links - very helpful - I decided to reconfigure everything from scratch, and checked this Passenger Box on the control panel, along with the HTTPS secure bit, added a certificate from 'Let's Encrypt SSL' and restarted my server.
Everything started working perfectly as required. I also added the headers for the 443 port under the location block for '/cable' in the CONF file - and added the http://www.domainnam.io in the production.rb file, with config.force_ssl set to true.

So, in conclusion, I understand the problem was with improper configuration of the passenger nginx integration.
Thank you @Camden for the links.